# Is it possible to deduce by a computer all the propositions from the Euclid's Elements from its postulates, common notions and definitions?

Tags: logic, computer-science, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, computational-mathematics

Similarly to an argument in logic, is it possible to deduce propositions by a computer from the Euclid's Elements just from postulates, common notions and definitions?

Comment: That's the whole idea behind the Elements in the first place, isn't it?

Comment: Are you asking if the postulates are complete by modern standards?  Hilbert wrote [The Foundations of Geometry](https://math.berkeley.edu/~wodzicki/160/Hilbert.pdf) in an attempt to fully formulate an axiom system for Euclidean Geometry.

Comment: The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_geometry) on the Foundations gives a pretty good survey of the issues Hilbert was interested in.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention the word "computer"

Comment: If the word "computer" is significant to your Question, you should expand on its significance   A one-line post does not become more adequate merely by adding the phrase "by a computer" to it.  Add more context.  E.g. are you familiar with "automatic theorem provers" and related software such as interactive proof assistant [COQ](https://coq.inria.fr/)?

Comment: Sorry I can't find a reference for it, but I recall reading about a college project using, I think it was Isabelle?, that automated the discovery of Euclid's elements, and even found shorter proofs for some of them.

Comment: Tarski [showed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms) that Euclidean Geometry is decidable.

Answer (score 3):

No. Euclid makes additional assumptions that aren't explicit. For example, he assumes two crossing lines have a common point (essentially the completeness axiom for real numbers).

Hilbert did work on building euclidean geometry on firm axiomatic basis, and if I recall correctly he needed around 20 axioms for it.